# Composer installs only what's in the require and require-dev blocks and not the dependencies when using local repository

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Under regular circumstances, if I delete the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file, and then run `composer install`, it will re-install everything, including the dependencies for the packages in the `require` and `require-dev` block. But when I use `composer install` from my local repository, it only installs what's inside `require` and `require-dev`.

This is an example `composer.json` of a clean Laravel 9 project:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",    
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

If I run `composer install` and set my local repository (add the following to `composer.json`):

```
"repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "http://localhost/" } ],
```

it will install only the 11 packages defined above inside `require` and `required-dev`, but not their dependencies. Then it will throw an error about missing things:

```
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found
```

Why does this happen? My local repository should work because when I compare the 11 packages installed by my local repository to the same 11 packages when installed by Packagist, they are the same, so I know my local repository should have the correct packages

(And of course the local repository also contains the rest of the packages, not the these 11)

Comment: In case it's relevant, how is your local repository set up? Is it using Satis, or Private Packagist, or what? Does it just contain mirrors of public packages, or modified forks of them?

Comment: Using Satis. My packages are zipped version of the original packages I took from `vendor`. But `satis.json` doesn't contain too much metadata, only name and version. You can see the json for each package from my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497845/19815685 . I suspect I need to add much more data, they original `composer.json` data that was in each package. You think that is the issue? Or it could be something more simple? Because it's weird, the `composer.json` file still exists in the zipped package, just not in Satis config metadata

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, to anyone encounters this problem in the future: even though each package zip file contains the `composer.json` file, it's not enough, since Satis does not read from that file, instead it reads the metadata from your repository.

So it's important to setup your `satis.json` to include all metadata fields that are required for Composer to work, so called `root` fields.

In my case I only used `require` and `autoload` fields in `satis.json`, which caused the issue.

After adding all the fields necessary - `require`, `autoload`, `conflict`, `replace`, `provide` and `suggest`, everything worked!

- Not all packages have all these fields, I wrote a script to add only the present fields